# How to supply tooltip for PaperDropdown that behaves nicely

Tags: dart-polymer, paper-elements

If I wrap the *paper-dropdown* that comes in the *paper_elements* example in a *core-tooltip*, the tip displays on hover as expected.

```dart
  <core-tooltip position="bottom" label="Choose country of residence">
    <paper-dropdown>
      <template repeat="{{countries}}">
        <paper-item label="{{name}}"></paper-item>
      </template>
    </paper-dropdown>
  </core-tooltip>
```

The problem is, after selecting an item, the tooltip is still displayed. Additionally in dartium and on chrome there is a fine blue line outlining the tip and the dropdown even as I hover over other elements.

[image]

Please explain what is going on and what is the best way to register with the *PaperDropdown* and/or *CoreTooltip* that it no longer has focus? I've tried calling focus() another element in the *onClick* *PaperItem* in my own examples and that did not seem to work.

Any suggestions on better approaches that might make tooltip unnecessary would be useful as well. The reason for a tooltip is there is no comparable *Floating* label as with *PaperInput* for the dropdown. So once a selection is made there is no description, thus the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have to do with focus. Mybe this improves your situation. If this is not what you want just add a comment:

```css
  core-tooltip:focus {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
```

Sometimes the tooltip seems just not to recognize that the element isn't mouse-overed anymore when not the mouse moved out but instead the mouse-overed element shrank away. I would report this as a bug in the `<core-overlay>` element.

Comment: The polymer team is working on some updates/improvements related to this problem: https://github.com/Polymer/core-tooltip/issues/13

Comment: This should be fixed in master and will be in the next release.

Comment: AFAIK, Polymer.dart 0.15.1+ is matched to Polymer.js 0.4.2 which has this fix, but I'm still seeing this same issue.